# Invalid route name, already in use: 'user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add followers to my rails application. I am seeing the following error when I run `rails s` to start my server:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'user'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :posts do
    member do
      post '/like' => 'posts#like'
    end
  end
  get ':username' => 'users#show', as: 'user'

  root 'home#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

---

It may be helpful to know that I added:

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Before I added the above, my rails app worked.

---

I'm sure it's probably a simple fix, but I am new to rails. I've been tinkering with routes and searching online for over an hour, trying to understand and solve the problem. I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable can guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Since you are using devise** there are some routes already created by `devise_for users` so avoid using such routes which has conflict with already defined routes. Instead of using `as: :user` put another relevant name like `as::user_profile`

**Hope it helps**

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, **Devise** routes and **Users** routes are conflicting. You need to change one of them. You can either put **Devise** under a specific prefix like,

```
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'auth'
resources :users
```

Reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface

Answer (score 0):

Please do not forget, that there is **"as"** option too.

```
devise_for :users, as: 'some_unique_prefix'
```